# bitcoin regtest no wallet RPC methods

Tags: bitcoind, regtest

I have compiled bitcoin core from the github repo using the regular instructions.
It compiled and it runs successfully

```
bitcoind --version
Bitcoin Core version v22.99.0-2f7b5c3039c7
```

However, it seems i have no wallet RPC methods

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest help | grep wallet
```

returns nothing.

How do i create a wallet?

Comment: What did your `configure` command look like?

Comment: @AndrewChow just `configure` no extra args. Im doing this in a container, i can post the entire dockerfile, if it would be useful (using ubuntu 20.1)

Comment: Do you have sqllite or bdb installed to build the wallet?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that i had no db lib as @meshcollider noted
after adding
`apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev` (on ubuntu)
and recompiling the wallet methods are there